# ASSERT failure in QCoreApplication : Simple QT Unit test failure?

Tags: python, qt, unit-testing, pyqt

I am new in Python / Qt programming.

I have downloaded this code : https://bitbucket.org/jmcgeheeiv/pyqttestexample/src/

but when i attempt to run unit test with " python -m unittest discover " i got this error :

.ASSERT failure in QCoreApplication: "there should be only one application object", file kernel/qcoreapplication.cpp, line 540
Abort

i don't understand what is wrong.

can someone help me please ?

Comment: As error message says, you probably have more than one QApplication created?

Comment: Yeah i know, but i don't understand where i have more than one Qapp...

Comment: Well where is your code?

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/jmcgeheeiv/pyqttestexample/src/ 
complete code i attempt to use

Comment: If you ask why something is not working you must before strip down the code to the absolute minimum size still showing the error. You cannot just present 20k code from someone and ask for debugging it. But if you had done it, chances are high you would have found the error yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setUp()` is called before each test case, which means a new `QApplication` is created for each test, and before the previous one has been destroyed.

Adding a `tearDown()` which resets `self.app` to None should work.

Comment: Thanks, its working in console now. But the initial project was working correctly on eclipse, and when i add tearDown() its not working any more.